# LeetCode question Removed Duplicates From Sorted List

Tags: python, linked-list

I tried the method where you go through the head, compare it to the curr of the new ListNode I made. If it doesn't exist already, add it. However, it looks like it doesn't work properly for duplicates so I switched the strategy to copying over the entire head into the new ListNode and updating curr.next if it equals curr's value to curr.next.next which worked. However, I still want to figure out why my previous method/strategy didn't work and how I can fix it.
Previous strategy I couldn't get to work:

```
class Solution(object):
def deleteDuplicates(self, head):
"""
:type head: ListNode
:rtype: ListNode
"""
if not head:
    return None

    temp = ListNode()
     curr = temp
    
        while head:
            if head.val != curr.val:
                curr.next = head
                head = head.next
                curr = curr.next
            else:
                head = head.next
        return temp.next
```

Example where it fails:

```
head = \[1,1,2,3,3\]
```

My output

```
\[1,2,3,3\]
```

Expected

```
\[1,2,3\]
```

It only goes into my if statement the 3 times because when I have a print statement under curr = curr.next, it just prints 1,2,3. However when it prints the final product it somehow gets another 3.

To fix this I added curr.next = None before temp.next but this won't work when head = [0,0,0]

Comment: Your title should reflect the technical problem you got stuck on, not what you were trying ot do/solve when you encountered that problem.

Comment: Also, please fix your formatting -- correct the indentation, take out any extra backslashes you added to try to make the formatter happy, etc.

Comment: When you say "Example where it fails" you should show us the actual code you ran. And, as Charles pointed out, don't insert extraneous backslashes. They aren't necessary if you surround your code with two lines of three backticks to create a literal block of text. Learning how to ask a good question is important. Your question is also not a minimal reproducible example. You don't show us your `ListNode` definition.